# On a step on a complex inequality with summation.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, summation, proof-explanation, roots-of-unity

To make it short I have a doubt in the last step of a complex number inequality, the problem is the next one

> Let complex numbers $z_1,z_2,z_3,...,z_n$ all modulus $1$ and $z_1+z_2+z_3+...+z_{2012}=0$ Show that.
> $$ \sum^{2012}_{k=1}\vert z-z_k \rvert \geq 2012 \  \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$$

The last step given in the book states that
$\vert \sum_{2012}^{k=1}(z\overline{z_k})-2012 \vert=2012$
However I cannot prove this, I suppose that if we somehow show that $\overline{z_1}+\overline{z_2}+\overline{z_3}+...+\overline{z_{2012}}=0$ then we would be done, However the only thing that ocurred to me is to manipulate the given expression $z_1+z_2+z_3+...+z_{2012}=0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\overline{z_1}}+\frac{1}{\overline{z_2}}+\frac{1}{\overline{z_3}}+....+\frac{1}{\overline{z}_{{2012}}}=0 $ But then we would have a nasty expression. Also the fact that the complex numbers sum to zero reminds of roots of unity but I didn't see a conection.

Comment: Can you check that last step, especially what's in the summation? IE Is it $ ( \sum |z \bar{z_k}| ) - 2012$ or $\sum( z\bar{z_k} ) - 2012)$? $\quad$ Do you know what is $ \overline{ z_1 + z_2 } $ and $ \bar{0}$?